# Show div on click and scroll down to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a div that when clicked on, pops open another div and scrolls down to it.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kq9G8/743/)'s my take on it but it is not working. What is the correct way?

`html`

```
<div class="image">
<img src="https://dotcms.com/contentAsset/image/47ffbc9c-f224-47a2-ba6c-  0fedb202dbe9/diagram1/filter/Scale/scale_w/500/scale_h/800">
</div>
<div id="box" style="display:none;"></div>
```

`jquery`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function() {
    $('#box').slideToggle("fast");

    $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $('#box').offset().top
     }, 2000);
     });

});
```

Comment: Your code is running fine. You just have to change the javascript framework from MooTools to jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `scrollIntoView()`

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.image').click(function() {
            $("#box").show()
             $('#box').get(0).scrollIntoView()
     });
  
    });
```

```css
#box{background-color:#000;height:100px;display:block;width:100%;}
.mage{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
<img src="https://dotcms.com/contentAsset/image/47ffbc9c-f224-47a2-ba6c-0fedb202dbe9/diagram1/filter/Scale/scale_w/500/scale_h/800">
</div>
<div id="box" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `display:none` inline css and add `display:none` to external css of `#box` div. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kq9G8/745/) is the updated fiddle

```
<div id="box">
</div>

#box{background-color:#000;height:100px;display:none;width:100%;}
```